# Microsoft bot framework : How to define the image path which exists in the solution itself

Tags: bots

I have stored the image inside the project itself, now I would like to display the image on the hero card, so I have mentioned the relative path. However the image is not appearing....

```
 List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
 cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "~/duck-on-a-rock.jpg", alt:"image1"));
```

But when I referred the image from some website and mention the same path on the  page like below that time the image is appearing.

```
 List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
 cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/t2/duck-on-a-rock.jpg", alt:"image1"));
```

Is it not possible to keep the image inside the project folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is a super old question, but google me brought here nonetheless. The solution I came across was to create a data url for your local resource. In node.js:

```
  const imageData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../resources/logo.png'));
  const base64Image = Buffer.from(imageData).toString('base64');

  const inlinePng = {
      name: 'logo.png',
      contentType: 'image/png',
      contentUrl: `data:image/png;base64,${ base64Image }`
  };
```

With an svg, you can skip the base64 encode:

```
const svgData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './resources/logo.svg'));

const inlineSvg = {
  name: 'logo',
  contentType: 'image/svg',
  contentUrl: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${ svgData }`,
};
```

See [Microsoft's docs for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#send-attachments) and C# samples.

Comment: I'd love to know why this is downvoted, so that I can provide better answers in the future. Examples provided are in a different language, but I would expect most readers to be capable of translating the concept (creating a data url from a local resource). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using DI approach: Pass one extra **IHostingEnvironment** variable to your dialog constructor.

```
    public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, T dialog, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _dialog = dialog;
        _env = env;
    }
```

And later you can use **_env.WebRootPath** to access your local storage (for bot emulator) or use environmental variable **WEBSITE_HOSTNAME** if you run bot in azure.

```
    private async Task SendWelcomeCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var card = new HeroCard();
        card.Title = "Welcome to Bot Framework!";
        var host = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME") != null ? ("https://" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")) : _env.WebRootPath + "/");
        var img = new Uri(host, "MyImage.jpg");
        card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage(img.AbsoluteUri) };
        var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I simply dropped **MyImage.jpg** image to *wwwroot* project folder and marked it as Content